# SQLSTATE 42000 (Error 102) Incorrect syntax near ')'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

**General Setting**

This is a weird question and I am sorry about that. I actually spent quite some time searching and analyzing our code. We have a job calling a stored procedure which selects some data and then calls other stored procedures (some which names are retrieved using the select-statements, since they might vary). It calls about 20 different of these stored procedures about 10'000 times (summed up the different calls), just varying the parameters. These stored procedures retrieve some data and then inserts the data into our databse.

**Version of SQL-Server**

This worked fine in Microsoft SQL-Server 2005, but since a little while we upgraded to SQL-Server 2012 (11.0.3000.0) and this problem seems to started occurring since then, or we simply were not aware of it before.

**Error**

So we get this error every time we execute it:

```
Executed as user: #DATABASEUSER_RMV_FOR_STACKOVERFLOW. Incorrect syntax near ')'. 
[SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 102)  Incorrect syntax near ')'. 
[SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 102)  Incorrect syntax near ')'. 
[SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 102)  Incorrect syntax near ')'. 
[SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 102)  Incorrect syntax near ')'. 
[SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 102)  Incorrect syntax near ')'. 
[SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 102)  Incorrect syntax near ')'. 
[SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 102)  Incorrect syntax near ')'. 
[SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 102)  Incorrect syntax near ')'. 
[SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 102)  Incorrect syntax near ')'. 
[SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 102).  The step failed.
```

I know this is very little information, but our scripts are pretty big and I would like to ask what some of you would to to figure out the problem.

**What I did so far**

I looked at the scripts, did some dry runs (b/c the entire script runs for about an hour... (it's a nightly job)). The dry runs worked fine. Also we hardly have opening brackets, and they always close. As soon as it retrieves data, after an hour of running it 'crashes' with this error...

So what I did:

- Dry runs (without actually loading the data but calling most of the stored procedures) - ok, success
- Called the main-store-procedure directly (not as job) - did not work either
- Read through the code searched for bracket-errors - ok, no bracket errors found
- Runned with different users: db-admin, my user - did not work either
- Search through Google/Stackoverflow/a littlbe bit through stackexchange in general

**Questions**

It looks like everything the script has to do, is done correctly and completely, so we do not understand why it does not return 'success' and throws this error message at us.

I could imagine that there might be a field it retrieves which contains an escape character... would that make sense?

Could I set like a universal breakpoint, that the execution of the script would break as soon as this 'error' occurs and show me what the data is causing this error... like debugging code in visual studio?

So my main question is: Could you please give me a hint/help how to approach this error in the best way? What I should do?

---

**Job**

```
EXEC MY_SCHEME.dbo.MY_STOREDPROCEDURE_MAIN
```

**MY_STOREDPROCEDURE_MAIN**

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
DECLARE @userId INT
DECLARE @fullHistory BIT

SELECT @userId = userId
FROM MY_SCHEME.dbo.USERS
WHERE loginname = 'SOME_NAME'

SET @fullHistory = 0

EXECUTE MY_SCHEME.dbo.spStartMyNightlyJob @userId=@userId, @processFullHistory=@fullHistory
```

**spStartMyNightlyJob**

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[spStartMyNightlyJob]
    @userId INT,
    @processFullHistory BIT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @logReport VARCHAR(255)
    SET @logReport = 'NightlyJob'

    INSERT INTO TEMP_LOGREPORT (text, report) VALUES('=======================================================================================================', @logReport)
    INSERT INTO TEMP_LOGREPORT (text, report) VALUES('NightlyJob started at ' + CAST(GETDATE() AS VARCHAR), @logReport)
    INSERT INTO TEMP_LOGREPORT (text, report) VALUES('=======================================================================================================', @logReport)

    DECLARE taskCursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR 
        SELECT
            r.taskId, link.Id, i.Description, link.externalId, rdef.name, rdir.fromDB, rdir.toDB,
            rdef.procedureName, rfs.fillStrategyId, rp.parameterId
        FROM MY_TASK r
        LEFT OUTER JOIN some_table_1 link
        ON r.LinkId = link.LinkId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN some_table_2 i
        ON link.Id = i.Id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN some_table_3_TASK_DEFINITION rdef
        ON r.taskDefinitionId = rdef.taskDefinitionId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN some_table_4_TASK_DIRECTION rdir
        ON rdef.directionId = rdir.directionId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN some_table_5_FILL_STRATEGY rfs
        ON rdef.fillStrategyId = rfs.fillStrategyId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN some_table_6_PARAMETER rp
        ON rdef.parameterId = rp.parameterId
        WHERE r.active = 1
        AND rdef.taskDefinitionId NOT LIKE 17


    DECLARE @taskId INT
    DECLARE @someOtherId INT
    DECLARE @someOtherName VARCHAR(255)
    DECLARE @externalSomeOtherId INT
    DECLARE @taskName VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @fromDB VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @toDB VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @storedProcedure VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @fillStrategyId INT
    DECLARE @parameterId INT

    OPEN taskCursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM taskCursor
    INTO
        @taskId, @someOtherId , @someOtherName , @externalSomeOtherId , @taskName, @fromDB, @toDB, @storedProcedure,
        @fillStrategyId, @parameterId

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
        INSERT INTO TEMP_LOGREPORT (text, report) VALUES('-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------', @logReport)
        INSERT INTO TEMP_LOGREPORT (text, report) VALUES('Performing task: ' + @taskName, @logReport)
        INSERT INTO TEMP_LOGREPORT (text, report) VALUES('Nightly Job between: ' + @fromDB + ' -> ' + @toDB, @logReport)
        INSERT INTO TEMP_LOGREPORT (text, report) VALUES('Executive procedure: ' + @storedProcedure, @logReport)
        INSERT INTO TEMP_LOGREPORT (text, report) VALUES('Involved : ' + @someOtherName + ' (' + CAST(@someOtherId AS VARCHAR) + ')', @logReport)

        EXECUTE @storedProcedure @someOtherId , @externalSomeOtherId , @fillStrategyId, @parameterId, @userId, @processFullHistory

        INSERT INTO TEMP_LOGREPORT (text, report) VALUES('', @logReport)

        SET @taskId = NULL
        SET @someOtherId = NULL
        SET @someOtherName = NULL
        SET @externalSomeOtherId = NULL
        SET @taskName = NULL
        SET @fromDB = NULL
        SET @toDB = NULL
        SET @storedProcedure = NULL
        SET @fillStrategyId = NULL
        SET @parameterId = NULL

        FETCH NEXT FROM taskCursor
        INTO
            @taskId, @taskId , @someOtherName , @externalSomeOtherId , @taskName, @fromDB, @toDB, @storedProcedure,
            @fillStrategyId, @parameterId
    END
    CLOSE taskCursor
    DEALLOCATE taskCursor

    INSERT INTO TEMP_LOGREPORT (text, report) VALUES('=======================================================================================================', @logReport)
    INSERT INTO TEMP_LOGREPORT (text, report) VALUES('NightlyJob finished at ' + CAST(GETDATE() AS VARCHAR), @logReport)
    INSERT INTO TEMP_LOGREPORT (text, report) VALUES('=======================================================================================================', @logReport)
    RETURN 0
END
```

After this it opens up to about 15 different stored procedures, depending which tasks are 'defined' every evening..

If I comment-out the actual execution of it

```
EXECUTE @storedProcedure @someOtherId , @externalSomeOtherId , @fillStrategyId, @parameterId, @userId, @processFullHistory
```

then it completes without error.

Thanks already for looking at my question ;-)

Comment: I think the problem is with your second `INSERT` statement.

Comment: because of the `CAST(GETDATE() AS VARCHAR)` ?

Comment: Yes. Probably you should enclose that within a single quote.

Comment: do you mean like: `''' + CAST(GETDATE() AS VARCHAR) + '''`. Because it is writing the Log-Table (or do you think it may cause a crash even though it is writing into the log?)

Comment: No harm in trying this out. Do try and let me know.

Comment: unfortunately this did not work :-( - I'm really sorry. I still get the same error.... may I ask if you have any other ideas? The weird thing is that the error occurs only when I entirely run the script (and that takes about an hour). Do you know of a Log-File which may contain more useful information than the one the job-history provides?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with your **2nd Insert statement.** Replace your old one with this.

```
create table #temp1 (text nvarchar(100),report nvarchar(500))
INSERT INTO #temp1 (text, report) VALUES('NightlyJob started at ' + ''  + CAST(GETDATE() AS VARCHAR) + '','Report')
select * from #temp1
```

Comment: Thanks Aishvaraya for your support - sorry I did not reply quicker. I tried your suggested code... as it is it works, but if I insert it into my code I still get my other bug. At the moment I think the bug is in the WHILE-loop where the 'EXECUTE' is done... if commented out it works (without the execute-part) However.. with the execute I get the error. I'm trying now to find a pattern and more information to figure out what the problem is